# Xcode 13.0 with Swift 5.5 will no longer build my project with an "import CreateML" statement, how to fix?

Tags: swift, xcode

After installing Xcode 13.0, which updates the version of Swift to 5.5, I am getting this error:

> Failed to build module 'CreateML'; this SDK is not supported by the
> compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.4
> (swiftlang-1205.0.24.14 clang-1205.0.19.54)', while this compiler is
> 'Apple Swift version 5.5 (swiftlang-1300.0.31.1 clang-1300.0.29.1)').
> Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK.

Installing and selecting toolchains back to 5.4 and even 5.3.3 doesn't help. Here's the error message for 5.4:

> Failed to build module 'CreateML' from its module interface; the
> compiler that produced it, 'Apple Swift version 5.4
> (swiftlang-1205.0.24.14 clang-1205.0.19.54)', may have used features
> that aren't supported by this compiler, 'Apple Swift version 5.4
> (swift-5.4-RELEASE)'

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you remember to repoint the tools at your new copy of Xcode 13? Did you remember to empty the DerivedData folder and restart?

Comment: Yes, changed the toolchain. Yes, deleted DerivedData and yes, restarted. Still gives the same error.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the issue. Did you remember to build for a device? Is it running iOS 15?

Comment: It”a a Mac app - building for MacOS Big Sur

Comment: That could be it. You may need Monterey.

Comment: I have confirmed the problem still persists for the latest Monterey beta.

Comment: Thanks. Apple doesn’t seem to support CreateML as a first class part of the OS. I’ve had problems before with mismatched versions of the library between Xcode and the OS.

Comment: Still not fixed in Monterey release.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed this after updating to Monterey and changing the build settings to target 12.0 (was 10.13 before).

Comment: facing same issue. Where we can find build settings

Comment: At the top left of Xcode, click on your Project Name, then again on the name below "PROJECT", select the "Build Setting tab to the right of that.

See also:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/CreatingProjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH31-SW1